# A command-line clipboard copy and paste utility?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, clipboard

In Windows I used command-line clipboard copy-and-paste utilities...

- `pclip.exe` and `gclip.exe`

These were UnixUtils ports for Windows (but they only handled plain text). There were a couple of other **native** Windows utilities which could write/extract any format.

I've looked for something similar in Synaptic Package Manager, but I can't find anything.

Is there something there, that I've missed? ... or maybe this is available in Bash scripting?

The type of utility I'd like will be able to read/write via std-in/std-out or file-in/file-out, and handle Unicode, Rich Text Format, picture, etc. clipboard formats...

NB: I'm not after a clipboard manager.

Comment: See related question from unix.SE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30093/copy-image-from-command-line-to-clipboard

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-clipboard

Comment: `vim[enter]"+P` **:3** *(run **vim** and then from `"`  register - i.e. system clipboard - paste text)*. Then you have (one of) the best text editor(s) at your finger tips, so you can `:w filename`. Also, I always run *vim* in *tmux* which means that if I need to copy a little text over to the terminal, I just select (with `v` or `V` for line selection) and then `"+y` (which yanks or copies to clipboard), then I make a new tmux pane and can <ctrl>+<shift>+v to paste. Additionally, I will occaisionally use `xsel -b > filename` if I need to write clipboard to a file. Cheers **^u^**

Comment: How about a when a complete non-GUI Ubuntu is being used through ssh from macOS Terminal app or analogue?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

### xsel

I am using [xsel](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xsel/) [Install xsel](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xsel), but I am only using it with plain text and unicode text.

`xsel` can copy and paste to three different "clipboards".

By default, it uses the *X Window System primary selection*, which is basically whatever is currently in selection. The X Window System also has a *secondary selection* (which isn't used much), and a *clipboard selection*. You're probably looking for the *clipboard selection*, since that's what the desktop environment (e.g. Gnome, KDE, XFCE) uses for its clipboard. To use that with xsel:

```
xsel --clipboard < new-clipboard-contents.txt
xsel --clipboard > current-clipboard-contents.txt
```

Comment: Adi... **xsel** seems(?) to be only text based (as you mentioned), so I'll look for a more comprehensive utility... However, it has been very interesting for me to read its **info** documentation... I knew that middle-clicking the mouse (in the Terminal) would paste the currently selected text into the command-line, but I didn't realize that this feature applies to most X apps... The most-recent text selection  can be pasted via a middle-click (but some apps seem to override it).. Two clipboards!.. Very handy.. .I must read more about the 3rd X-selection buffer.

Comment: xsel does work with Unicode text. You can read more about X clipboards on the freedesktop wiki pages: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/ClipboardsWiki .

Comment: I've got to get my head around this new info.. 3 clipboards! PRIMARY, SECONDARY, CLIPBOARD... This is very different to what I'm used to in windows... The 3rd one "CLIPBOARD" seems to be the same as a Windows / Mac clipboard... but it is ridiculously late here.. I'll get back to this tomorrow... (Inersting, but too much to read now..)

Comment: Thanks... `xsel` does the job (for text)... Something might turn up for other formats.

Comment: Useful alias is `alias xsel='xsel --clipboard'`.

Comment: `xsel -b` is short for `xsel --clipboard`.

Comment: Sir you deserve the Nix medal of honor...

Comment: Your link reveals Ubuntu 13 as the last available  version.

Comment: Worked like a charm! `cat "hello" | xsel --clipboard`

Answer (score 114):

### [xclip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/)

[Install xclip](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xclip) may be one of your choices.

```
cat samples.sh | xclip -sel clip
```

you can also setting it in the .bashrc file using alias.

```
alias clipboard='xclip -sel clip'
```

The key to paste binary data to a file with `xclip` is to tell what [Media Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) you have on clipboard. For PNG you can:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o > "`date '+%Y-%m-%d_%T'`.png"
```

So now on `~/Dropbox/.mybashrc` ;) you can add an alias (clipboard2photo) to easily paste to image file (maybe someday [we'll have it on Nautilus](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/687749)).

Comment: This looks good, but I just haven't had a chance to look into it, yet... I will do that ASAP...

Comment: xclip also only handles text selections.

Comment: Thanks... `xclip` works fine for text  (it is very similar to xsel) ... and as for the  "other" formats, I've come to realize that the Linux clipboard system is quite different to Windows, and I've got a bit more reading to do first...

Comment: Also, the command can be as short as `xclip -se c`

Comment: I don't understand why this is not in the man page

Comment: I get this when trying to paste images to file Error: target image/png not available

Comment: Didn't work for me. But `xsel` worked. Running Ubuntu 17.04 GNOME.

Comment: Can't copy image to clipboard when having a Qt environment like KDE or LXQT with xclip.

Comment: Looks like the first link points to a page that states that it has moved to github. Link it points to is https://github.com/astrand/xclip

Comment: @xerostomus answer is also helpful for understanding how to show what mime types are in the clipboard: https://askubuntu.com/a/814412/340383

Comment: [Here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/540) is the Nautilus issue upstream

Answer (score 12):

## [Parcellite](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/parcellite)

I've used parcellite for many years as a clipboard manager. It runs in the Notification Area and offers many options for managing both Primary Selection and standard freedesktop.org Clipboard.

[image: Tray Icon]

It's been my answer to managing clipboard items.

[image: Preferences]

Comment: This looks like a good panel-app.. The "Actions" is handy... but unfortunately its not the type of tool I am looking for.. I've re-worded my question to include some more specific info...  Maybe the exact thing I'm after is an obscure Python script, or the like... There were a couple of very good **native** Windows-only utilities available, so I'd think an equivalent would be floating around somewhere in the Ubuntu/Linux world...

Comment: FYI, Parcellite has a cool feature - history of copied text. To activate auto-paste from history dialog, you should also `install xdotool`

Answer (score 12):

I recently came across the tools `xclip-copyfile`, `xclip-cutfile`, and `xclip-pastefile` (package [`xclip`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xclip)). These tools allow you to copy/cut/paste entire files via the command line.

You can see their [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xclip-copyfile.1.html) here.

Answer (score 9):

### [clipit](https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt)

clipit is a clipboard manager for GTK+ that allows piping text from the command line:

```
ls | clipit
```

Comment: I am using ClipIt for other reasons and didn't know it's capable of getting data from terminal. Thanks a lot for that info.

Comment: (clipit:53904): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:07:38.771: cannot open display:

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) for this. From the website:

> Clipboard manager with advanced features
>
> - CopyQ is clipboard manager with searchable and editable history.
> - Supports Linux and Windows.
> - Experimental support for OS X 10.9+.
> - Store text, HTML, images and any other custom format.
> - Advanced command-line interface and scripting.

To copy a text file:

```
copyq action "cat /tmp/file.txt" "" && copyq select 0
```

To copy an image (you need to indicate the MIME type):

```
copyq write image/png - < file.png && copyq select 0
```

To copy a data file (you need to indicate the MIME type):

```
copyq write application/pdf - < file.pdf && copyq select 0
```

Check their wiki for more [documentation and usage examples](http://sourceforge.net/p/copyq/wiki/Home/).

You can install it either via the [ppa:noobslab/indicators](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/indicators) PPA or by manually downloading prepackaged `.deb` files of latest stable from the project's [Downloads section](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/releases).

Comment: The ppa isn't up to date, at least for Ubuntu 16.04, it's better to download it from [CopyQ's releases GitHub site](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/releases) directly.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to copy some text to the clipboard:

`echo -n "some-text" | xclip -selection clipboard`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pastie](https://launchpad.net/%7Ehel-sheep/+archive/pastie)

A new clipboard manager with Indicator Applet support was recently released (though not in the archive yet). In addition to tracking text clipboard history it will also capture and persist data clipboard entries as well (Files, Folders, etc) which may be useful if you manipulate files a lot via a GUI/Clipboard environment.

[image]

[You can add the following PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them): `ppa:hel-sheep/pastie`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Marco, but I don't have any need for a clipboard manager. Occasionally I'll paste some temporary text into a text file , but I actually find that a "history manager" slows things down (but that's just me).. I'm really after a command-line tool which can **selectively** extract/store a **specific** format from/to the clipboad.. I am assuming the Ubuntu clipboard is similar to the Windows one (I'd be stunned if it was significantly different, because users' requirements are the same on any platform)... I'm sure someone will find your suggestion useful.

Answer (score 2):

For RTF format I use this procedure:
I copy text into clipboard in the application. If I am unsure whether it is rtf or what, I use this command to verify:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -o -t TARGETS
```

When it prints out something like this:

TARGETS

text/rtf

text/richtext

So I cannot resist to exclaim quite aloud: "Gee, that is genious! God bless linux!" After that shot prayer, just obvious thing follows:

```
xclip  -selection clipboard -o -t text/rtf > mypreciousRTFcontent.rtf
```

Then I process it all in libreoffice and send to all my friends as a spam.

:-)

Answer (score 1):

How about [GPaste daemon settings](https://github.com/Keruspe/GPaste), a clipboard management daemon applet with DBus interface:

- GPaste is a clipboard management suite for GNOME written in Vala
- GPaste settings look has been updated to better fit with recent GNOME
- Daemon now fully evenmential (no more polling, less power consuption)
- GPasteClipboard now has a “owner-change” signal similar to GtkClipboard’s one
- New setting to set the maximum amount of memory used by data in history
- FIFO mode has been dropped (lacking design)
- Code cleanup and modernisation
- g_paste_history_add is now transfer full
- g_paste_keybinder_add_keybinding is now transfer full

---

**Installation:**

To install it in **Ubuntu 13.10**, **13.04**, **12.10** or **12.04**, use the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-gpaste
```

**Or** install `gpaste` through `synaptic package manager` (and also `gnome-shell-extensions-gpaste` if you use Gnome-Shell).

**Another** option is the installation through `software-center`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to develop a better solution that isn't a clipboard manager, found at https://github.com/baitisj/copypasta . It doesn't handle RTF and HTML correctly quite yet, and large images pose problems, but feel free to fork and submit patches.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is. Try `tmux` which is more advanced than `screen`. To install tmux, type this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

Also try `gpm`. The commands `gpm` and `tmux` might be a good combination...

Comment: Screen is a multiple-terminal emulator not a clipboard manager.

Comment: It seems that **screen** and **tmux** only work at the terminal level (I can't find any reference to **"clipboard"** in either of their **info** documentation)... What I'm looking for is a  **system-wide clipboard** copy and paste utility...  I probably should not have used *terminal* as a tag... The type of utility I want will be able to read/write via std-in/std-out or file-in/file-out, and handle  Unicode/Rich-text/Picture/etc clipboard formats...

Comment: I've just found a reference on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-clipboard)... `gpm` is for a non-X terminal "clipboard", and `GNU screen` has its own "clipboard" also...  I see now why you mentioned them... This is great info, and it has led me into a deeper understanding of what goes on behind the scenes... I'll stick to the basic Xterm "selections system" (clipboad) for now.. The Linux "clipboard" seems to be so different to Windows, that what I was looking for may be done in a very different way here.. +1 :)