# VIM Overwrite instead of edit

Tags: command-line, vim, clipboard

I am currently running the following two commands.

```
\rm myfile
vim myfile
```

Then, <kbd>i</kbd>, to enter insert mode, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> to paste

Basically I have text on my clipboard that I would like to copy and overwrite my current file.

Can this be done with less work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11925/a-command-line-clipboard-copy-and-paste-utility). You can use `xsel` to paste directly from your clipboard into a file, using `>` to overwrite the original file.

`xsel --clipboard > path/to/file.txt`