# Ctrl+Shift+C/Ctrl+Shift+V is not working in the console as soon as I set keyboard layout switch on Ctrl+Shift

Tags: 18.04, gnome, kubuntu, kde

I tried this on Ubuntu and Kubuntu. Result is the same. How I can fix copy/pase in the console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [copy and paste doesn't work in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546669/copy-and-paste-doesnt-work-in-terminal)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language).

Comment: You need to use patched Xorg from [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys), but it will not work with GNOME sHell.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on some terminals (when the keyboard language is different from the system language).

On these terminals I have verified that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> pastes the contents of the clipboard if I lift my finger from the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (while holding down the other two keys). The procedure for copying is similar.

It's strange and not very functional but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand what you mean. Can you tell us a way to reproduce this issue?

As a workaround you you can **select** the text you want to copy and **press** the mouse wheel. This will copy and paste your selection.

Comment: By default you can use Ctrl+Shift+V/Ctrl+Shift+C in console (on Ubuntu and Kubuntu), but if you will set setting [this](https://sun9-55.userapi.com/c206624/v206624826/e8375/-VbA69glnkk.jpg), Ctrl+Shift+V/Ctrl+Shift+C will work no longer. In Ubuntu you can use Gnome Tweaks to apply the same option (switch layout on Ctrl+Shift).

Comment: I believe it has to do with the order that the OS resolves the pressing of the buttons. You have reserved the Ctrl+Shift combination for switching layouts. I'm no expert but I think that the OS catches the event before the terminal so only one operation is completed, the switching of the layout. 
If I'm correct, your only option is to change the combination to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could change Shortcuts preferences in terminal to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

**Edit** -> **Preferences** -> **Shortcuts**

[image]

The same could be performed for Konsole:

**Settings** -> **Configure Shortcuts**

[image]

Or just change layout switching Shortcut to something else in **Applications** -> **Settings** -> **Devices** -> **Keyboard Shortcuts** under ***Typing*** section.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is sad that I have to change my shortcut habits to use Linux :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i solved it, Just follow my steps :

**1.** Open your *Terminal / console* , using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]

**2.** From `Edit > Preferences > Shortcuts`, Look for copy/paste and double click and type your shortcut , Then `Close`.

**Note :**

Default shortcut for copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Default shortcut for paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

[image]

Now, you can copy and paste in your terminal, This way worked with me Ubuntu 18.04.

Hope that helps you to solve your issue.