# How do I paste to terminal executable content by command line?

Tags: command-line, aws

I want to copy a file to clipboard and then execute it as we do with "ctrl+shift+v", but the copy and paste on line command.

In my case I can't just run a .sh. I have to copy and paste.

I want to connect to ssh and run a command. When I use paste, it works.

I want to see what is going on the terminal, not just send a script to run.

No keyboard keys, just command line.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, even with the recent edit. Do you want to connect from a command line on one machine with no GUI, to the cli on another machine via ssh, and run a series of commands? Are these commands already in a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand what you are trying to achieve, but you can easily run long commands or scripts without storing them as a file by using Bash's command editor.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. This will bring up your default editor, usually `nano`.

In here you can now easily paste the commands or the full script you want to run.

When you're finished, exit `nano` saving the changes by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> ("Exit"), then answer <kbd>Y</kbd> (or whatever letter represents "Yes" in your locale) when asked whether to "Save modified buffer". Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the proposed temporary file name.

As soon as the editor terminates, Bash will run the temporary script and then delete it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to send file straight to "sh" without using the clipboard:

```
sh < file.sh
```

Or alternatively, to run the file without spawning a new process:

```
`cat file.sh`
```

If you really need to use the clipboard, refer to [A command-line clipboard copy and paste utility?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11925/a-command-line-clipboard-copy-and-paste-utility)

Comment: What I want to run is on a file. But it should execute like pasting. I cant ./file.sh it doesn't work for my purpose.

Comment: Does the file contain shell commands, like a regular .sh file? In that case my second example should work like pasting into the console. If not, please explain what difference the pasting does in your situation.

Comment: I will try it right know

Comment: I don't think `\`cat file\`` will work. backticks are meant as a process substitution for another command , you would need to use something like `eval \`cat file.sh\``

Comment: It does work, I tried it myself before posting. :)

Comment: It works on normal situations. But after a ssh it doesn't.