# Alternate for 'clip' command in ubuntu

Tags: clipboard, python-2.7, xdotool

I am using a python program to copy an input and pasting the output to chrome browser input field .

For windows there is the 'clip' command that pastes the data.

```
name = "งดดา"
command = 'echo ' + name.strip() + '| clip'
os.system(command)
```

This works perfectly in windows. 
I am having issue with pasting the value to input field in Ubuntu.
I have tried various ways but have not succeeded yet.
I have used Xdo Library which seems to work for standard English words and numbers but doesnot work prefectly for Thai text. Here is the link to the code i have used [XDO code for paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715121/pasting-on-input-field-via-python).

I believe there is an alterante for 'clip' command in Ubuntu that will do the trick.

The [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11925/a-command-line-clipboard-copy-and-paste-utility) here deals with files, but I am using specific texts (Thai texts to be precise which requires tis-620 decoding) which are not supported easily.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by using xdotool and xsel

```
def cb(name):
     paste = 'xdotool key ctrl+v'
     enter = 'xdotool key Tab'
     print("Executing *******************")
     command = 'echo '+ name.strip()+' | xsel -b'
     print ("command copy > ",command)
     os.system(command)
     print ("command paste> ",paste)
     os.system(paste)
     print ("command enter> ",enter)
     os.system(enter)
```

Name is any string value that can be sent as argument (number, alphabets , Thai text).

1. First I copy the name to the clipboard.
2. Second i paste the input from the clipboard.
3. Third i press (simulate ) tab and move to the next input box.

Hope this helps someone in future .