# Nautilus: copy file into clipboard with command line

Tags: command-line, nautilus, clipboard

When opening `nautilus`, choose a file and click `ctrl+c` copy the file into clipboard so that I can paste it in somewhere else in `nautilus`. And if the file is an image, I can even paste it in `libreoffice`. I want to know whether I can achieve the same effect as `ctrl+c` in command line without opening `nautilus`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A command-line clipboard copy and paste utility?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11925/a-command-line-clipboard-copy-and-paste-utility)

Comment: @Maythux Not exactly, `xsel` can only deal with text, but I want to deal with files with general type, especially image. `xclip` seems to be able to do this, but I do not know exactly how to do it. It seems that I have to specify a `target` in `xclip -t`, but I do not know exactly what type of `target` I should specify.

Answer (score 1):

`-target` is a way for *you* to describe the content of the selection. In that sense, it's possible to label the *selection* incorrectly. It has more to do with how the receiving program handles atoms. LibreOffice in your example handles MIME targets.

```
$ file --mime example.png 
example.png: image/png; charset=binary

$ xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i example.png
```

You can list targets of the current selection with the special [atom](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2.6.2) name TARGETS

```
$ xclip -selection clipboard -t TARGETS -o  
TARGETS  
image/png
```

Next example is Nautilus, the *selection* target is text/plain and a copy/paste has the format:

```
x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///path/to/file.txt
```

Gives the xclip selection:

```
xclip -sel clip -t text/plain <(printf %s\\n x-special/nautilus-clipboard copy file:///path/to/file.txt)
```

Comment: Yes, this is a reasonable answer. And it works with many software such as `libreoffice`. But it does not work with `nautilus`, that is, I cannot paste it in `nautilus` with `ctrl+v`. However, if I press `ctrl+c` after selecting a file in `nautilus`, the paste function is available for both `nautilus` and `libreoffice`. It seems that `nautilus` uses another different `target`, something like `x-special/nautilus-clipboard`. But I cannot figure it out clearly, because specifying  the `target` with  `x-special/nautilus-clipboard` also does not work.

Comment: have you tried using a uri "file:///path/to/file.ext" with that target

Comment: I have tried `echo "file:///path/to/file.png"| xclip -i -sel clipboard -target text/uri ` but it does not work.@bac0n

Comment: `-t text/uri-list` ?

Comment: Yes, the post above is my typo. Sorry for that.